# node mongoose parse JSON payload in request.body

Tags: node.js, mongoose, body-parser

I am currently creating a node server and testing with a rest client. I would like to send JSON in a POST request, parse the json and initialize a new mongoose.model object with said payload, and then store it in the DB.

It appears that this requires [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser), an NPM package that used to be part of express. Getting internal server errors. I have also made sure to supply the correct headers(Content-type: application/json).

The main code which I included is currently working and saving to the database, but I am using local dummy data instead of a new user instantiated from the request body. This is the JSON that I would like to instantiate a new user with.

```
{     "_id": 10,     "email": "abc@gmail.com",     "acct": "12345678",     "phone": 9785551212,     "cars": [],     "address": {         "street": "123 Main St.",         "city": "boston",         "state": "ma",         "zip": 2903 }}
```

In my reading, I found many different ways which should work but do not:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));

app.use(require('connect').bodyParser());
```

Nothing that I have tried has worked, and I always get internal server errors. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
   var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
//var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


var userSchema = Schema({
    _id: Number,
    email: String,
    acct: String,
    address: {
        street: String,
        city: String,
        state: String,
        zip: Number
    },
    phone: Number,
    cars: [{type: Schema.Types.Number, ref: "Car" }]
});

var carSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    _owner: {type: Number, ref: 'User'},
    make: String,
    model: String,
    year: String,
    color: String,
    plate: String
});


var Car = mongoose.model('Car', carSchema);
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

var sampleUser = new User({
    "_id": 10,
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "acct": 12345678,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "address": {
        "street": "123 Main St.",
        "city": "Boston",
        "state": "Ma",
        "zip": "02903"
    },
    "phone": "9785551212"
});

var car1 = new Car({
    _id : 51,
    _owner: sampleUser._id,
    make: "saab",
    model: "9000",
    year: "1997",
    color: "navy",
    plate: "777000"
});


app.post = function(request, response) {

    var db = mongoose.connection;
    mongoose.connect(process.env.MongoConnectionString);
    db.on('error', function () {

        response.send(500, {message: 'Failed to connect to mongo'});
    });

    db.once('open', function callback() {
        console.log("Sucessfully Logged into mongo");


        //this is the trouble line. I want to use reqest.body, 
        //or json.parse/json.stringify to   
        //parse my json and initialize a new user.

       //var user = new User(request.body);

        sampleUser.save(function (err) {
            if (err)
                return console.log('insert error');
        });



        //save the car to the db
        car1.save(function (err) {
            if (err)
                return console.log('insert error');
        });
        //push the car into the user.cars array and save
        sampleUser.cars.push(car1);
        sampleUser.save();

        //post response
        response.send(statusCodes.OK, sampleUser.cars);




    });

}
```

Comment: Remove the last 2 app.use

Comment: I know that, thats like saying remove the JSON from your code just because its also in the stack overflow post! They are not in my code in this post or in my IDE! I only included those app.use lines for context so that people would know I have at least tried them. Thank you though.

Comment: Can you add the detail of the internal  serrver error,  the log in the console

Answer (score 0):

To instantiate a new Mongoose.model object using a JSON payload in request.body, simply set each field as seen below.

Confusion arrises when anything similar to the following is attempted:

```
var x = new X(request.body).
```

That being said, I would like to know if the above code is possible.

The request header must have Content-Type: application/json, and the following body-parser code should be present. In my case, address contains several json fields, so it appears that body parser should work in all scenarios if you do what I did below.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json()) 

var user = new users({
            _id: request.body._id,
            email:request.body.email,
            account:request.body.account,
            name:request.body.name,
            address:request.body.address,
            phone:request.body.phone
        });
```